# Как убрать ограничение времени в datetime после 23:59:59?

Tags: discord.py

После 23:59:59 времени в войсе у меня начинаются считаться дни, как я могу убрать это ограничение?

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    with open('c:/Python/TOXBOT/database.json', 'r') as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)
    if not str(member.id) in data:
        voice_join_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        data[str(member.id)]["Время"] = voice_join_time
    else:
        if member.voice:
            voice_leave_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            voice_join_time = data[str(member.id)]['Время']
            calculate_time = (datetime.datetime.strptime(voice_leave_time, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(voice_join_time, '%H:%M:%S'))
            data[str(member.id)]["Время"] = f'{calculate_time}'
        elif not member.voice:
            voice_leave_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            voice_join_time = data[str(member.id)]['Время']
            calculate_time = (datetime.datetime.strptime(voice_leave_time, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(voice_join_time, '%H:%M:%S'))
            data[str(member.id)]["Время"] = f'{calculate_time}'
            data[str(member.id)]["Онлайн"] = f'{calculate_time}'
```

Comment: никак, но можно брать из дб тайм обджект и преобразовать его

Comment: поподробнее??00))

Comment: вы выводите без изменений время из дб?

Comment: как я могу это сделать если бот автоматически отнимает время при котором получается -1 day